# How do I access jQuery AutoComplete extraParams with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, ashx, generic-handler

I'm using the following jQuery script to send a 'Make' parameter to filter my 'Models':

```
$(document).ready(function () { $(".autocomplete_make").autocomplete("/AutoComplete/Make.ashx"); });
$(document).ready
    (function () {
        $(".autocomplete_model").autocomplete("/AutoComplete/Model.ashx"
                                                    , extraParams: {
                                                        make: function() {return $(".autocomplete_make").val(); }
                                                    }
                                                   );
    });
```

The text entered is passed to the .ashx file as a 'q' querystring, however, I'm not sure how I access my extraParam 'Make' so I can pass this to my stored procedure in the Generic Handler file. How do I do this?

Thanks,
Curt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

`context.Request("make")`

Which I believe you know already.

The only other problem I see is that your javascript looks a little flawed because you are not passing in an object as the second parameter (the options).

Here is the corrected code (I hope):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".autocomplete_model").autocomplete("/AutoComplete/Model.ashx", {
    extraParams: {
      make: function() {
        return $(".autocomplete_make").val(); 
      }
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its still not working. I've had a check on FireBug and the URL being posted is:

GET http://domainname.com/AutoComplete/Model.ashx?q=p&limit=150&timestamp=1281974977218

Shouldnt this include "Make" as a query string? Cheers

Comment: it should include make, that is weird that it isn't...  Are you sure the you updated the code to exactly what is above?  also,is there any other related code?

Comment: Looks like it was a cache issue, alls working fine! Cheers Bob! :D

Comment: glad you figured it out @Curt